# Stop div from shifting down when text is added

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place some text inside a square div. The only problem is that it shifts the div that the text is in down a lot. Does anyone know how I can get the div back to its original position?

Here is the html:

```
<div id="squarecontainer">
    <div id="square1">
        <p>Easy to Manage</p>
    </div>
    <div id="square2">

    </div>
    <div id="square3">

    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the css:

```
#squarecontainer{
    text-align: center;
}

#square1{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 100px;
    height: 310px;
    width: 310px;
    margin-top: 72px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

#square2{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 310px;
    width: 310px;
    margin-top: 72px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

#square3{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 100px;
    height: 310px;
    width: 310px;
    margin-top: 72px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

`#square1` is the div that shifts really far down when I added the "Easy to Manage" text.

Fiddle link demonstrating the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/RgywE/

Comment: hi sorry if i don't really get what your problem and what you want to achieve can you show image or what to make more easy to understand. if posible..

Comment: by the way i made [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/RgywE/) but cant figure out what the problem.

Comment: i found the solution below. adding verticle-align: top; moved it back up. Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found the solution. By adding `vertical-align: top;` it moved the div back. don't know why it worked, but it did.

Answer (score 15):

Going to add on to [zachstarnes's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15217010/2129835).

The problem is that the [`vertical-align` by default is set to `baseline`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp).

> Align the baseline of the element with the baseline of the parent element. This is default

Since the other divs are empty, their baseline default to the bottom of the div. Notice if as you fill in text they will all start to shift down until they all have content in them.

Depending on how you want the divs to line up with each other change the `vertical-align` property to something other `baseline`.

---

[image: vertical-align: baseline]

Comment: I feel like this explanation needs some work, it doesn't completely make sense to me. I get that the baseline of a box with text in it is the baseline of the bottom-most text element, and that it aligns this different baseline with the baseline of the parent element (which is the bottom margin since it has no text), but then the parent element expands. Doesn't that mean that its bottom margin and consequently its baseline shifts as well? Which would mean the baseline of the child element no longer aligns with the baseline of the parent. Confusing...

Answer (score 3):

Give position to your `p` tag. Problem will be solved.

```
#square1 p {
      position:absolute;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RgywE/2/)**

Comment: I had to use `pc` instead of `%` as the width units to make it work for different window sizes.

Answer (score 3):

**Reason why this happens**, it happens for `inline-block` elements :

In a inline-level (inline-block) you have to specify the vertical alignment of text. So in essence, without setting where the vertical alignment is, the content is placed in its default place which is baseline. This is why your text offsetted your layout.

Answer (score 2):

Using this solves the problem:

```
#square1 {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `word-wrap` property

```
div[id^="square"]{
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

You can specify either `normal` or `break-word` value with the `word-wrap` property. `Normal` means the text will extend the boundaries of the box. `Break-word` means the text will wrap to next line.