# Div boxes are moving down if i put text into it

Tags: html, css

I built four div boxes with content in them. First of all, there was blindtext into it and there were no problems. But now when I want to put my content into the boxes and I put some text into the first box, for example, the other three are going down by the same amount.

The second thing is, is there some way how I can make the text more compact? Like the other three boxes where the blind text is. Because in the first one there is much room between couple words. I heard something about css break? But I don't know if it's the right one.

```
.skillcontainer {
max-width: 23%;
min-width: 200px;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
margin-left:1.4em;
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/R5bSn/2/) you can see what I mean. And also with the text for example if you make the window bigger you see that under 22% there is empty space.

Comment: you have too much code in your fiddle cut it down to the relevant parts

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/R5bSn/4/ here is the correct code

Comment: both works.(the float left--- dont know why someone deleted  ) thanks guys. :) and does someone know how i can fix it with the text. So that it loos a lil bit better . would be cool if it would be look like the other three ones

http://i41.tinypic.com/2s6lrx2.jpg here is pic of what i mean

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop div from shifting down when text is added](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15216880/stop-div-from-shifting-down-when-text-is-added)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Float 'em!

```
.skillcontainer {
max-width: 23%;
min-width: 200px;
display: block;
position: relative;
margin-left: 1.4em;
float: left;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R5bSn/7/).

Answer (score 2):

No need to float them...you just have to add

```
 .wrapper {vertical-align:top; }
```

to your code...as the internal items are inline-block.

**[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/bmrLV/)**