# How to avoid floating of div with chaging text length?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am creating a div that will contain some text. However, the div starts to float when the text is longer. I would like to achieve a fixed position of the div, even if the string entered is longer.
I have checked several sources, but the suggested information does not apply to my code [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15216880/stop-div-from-shifting-down-when-text-is-added). The suggestion to add `vertical-align: top;`to my css had no effect. Please see the working example below: [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-leaf-1hzdn?file=/src/styles.css):

JS

```
function SinglePlaceMediumCard(props) {
  const {
      profileImage = "https://cdn.fastly.picmonkey.com/contentful/h6goo9gw1hh6/2sNZtFAWOdP1lmQ33VwRN3/24e953b920a9cd0ff2e1d587742a2472/1-intro-photo-final.jpg?w=1200&h=992&q=70&fm=webp",
      username = "USERNAME123", // with a longer username the div postion changes
      userShortTitle="SHORTTITLE", // same here with a longer short Title the div postion changes
      textColor="black",
      ...rest
  } = props;

  return (
      <div id="spm_card_container">
          <div id="avatar_container">
              <img id="detail_avatar" src={profileImage} />
          </div>

          <div id="user_info">
              <span id="place_name" style={{ color: `${textColor}` }}>
                  {username}
              </span>
              <span
                  id="username"
                  style={{
                      marginLeft: 0,
                      paddingTop: 0,
                      color: `${textColor}`,
                  }}
              >
                  {userShortTitle}
              </span>
          </div>
      </div>
  );
}

export default SinglePlaceMediumCard;
```

CSS

```
#spm_card_container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  /*border: #F16852 solid 1px;*/
  background-color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Turns off copy images Chrome all / Safari all */
  -moz-user-select: none; /* Turns off copy images Firefox all */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* Turns off copy images IE 10+ */
  user-select: none; /* Turns off copy images Likely future */
  cursor: pointer;
}

#spm_card_container > div {
  /*border: green solid 2px;*/
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#avatar_container {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

#avatar_container img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

#spm_card_container #user_info {
  padding-top: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  /*align-items: center;*/
  height: 70%;
}

#place_name {
  /*font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;*/
  font-weight: 800; /*Semi-Bold = 600*/ /*Bold = 700*/
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  /*float:left;*/
}

#username {
  font-weight: 500; /*Semi-Bold = 600*/ /*Bold = 700*/
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  /*float:left;*/
}

#detail_avatar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

I am happy for any clarification.

Comment: Are you sure this link is correct ? https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-paper-mnx1k?file=/src/index.js

Comment: i replaced the link. Is it working for you?

Comment: Yes it is ok now, and how do you want to be as result ?

Comment: if you increase the length of the 'username = "USERNAME123"', the entire div moves, but the div should stay fixed in place even if the length of the username increases. See also my comment in the JS code section.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `width` and `height` from `#spm_card_container`

```
#spm_card_container {
  /*border: #F16852 solid 1px;*/
  background-color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Turns off copy images Chrome all / Safari all */
  -moz-user-select: none; /* Turns off copy images Firefox all */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* Turns off copy images IE 10+ */
  user-select: none; /* Turns off copy images Likely future */
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the css property `word-break: break-all;` should fix the problem

```
#place_name {
  /*font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;*/
  font-weight: 800; /*Semi-Bold = 600*/ /*Bold = 700*/
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  word-break: break-all; // <------
  /*float:left;*/
}
```

Also, you could remove/adjust the specified width of `#spm_card_container` if it doesnt fit.